# Xamarin Forms UWP: Reference to type 'Assembly' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

Already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706578/reference-to-type-assembly-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-runtime-but-it-co) related to this issue, but the solution there is not solving the issue now for another project.

My error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS7069 Reference to type 'Assembly' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found

I have this problem after updating xamarin forms to 3.4.0.1008975 from 2.5.0.121934. Problem is only on the UWP part. Android and IOS apps are working fine.

Error lines:

```
var rendererAssemblies = new List<Assembly>
   {
       typeof(ImageCircleRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
   };
rendererAssemblies.AddRange(Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, rendererAssemblies);
```

Another solution found on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289010/reference-to-type-assembly-claims-it-is-defined-in-system-runtime-but-it-co). The solution on this thread is downgrading the xamarin forms to version 2.5.1.527436 in all the projects. But I can't do that in my project, because I am using some features that are available in the latest xamarin forms.

So how can I fix this issue without degrading the xamarin forms?

Comment: Could you share more detail about `ImageCircleRenderer` class? I create a blank app and add `Rg.Plugins.Popup`, it works well.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is not a class, it the image circle plugin, Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle

Comment: Ok, I got I will test it again.

Comment: I get an error, Please downgrade xamarin.form version. Please try to remove `Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle` first and update your xamarin forms to `3.4.0.1009999` then re-install Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle 3.1.1.1-beta.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Getting following error when installing the imagecircle 3.1.1-beta at the last step. Could not install package 'Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle 3.1.1.1-beta'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: You project is Portable type ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes

Comment: What's your uwp target version and min version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Min version: Windows 10 nov update(10.0; build 10586)
Target version: Windows 10 version 1803(10.0; build 17134)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196319/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: this is .net standard issue. update MinVersion to at least 16299

Comment: latest xamarin forms is v4+ why use v3.4?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Updated the min version to windows 10 fall creators update(10.0; Build 16299), no change in the error. Should I change the target version? Current target version is Windows 10 version 1803(10.0; Build 17134).

Comment: @Prateek Updated the xamarin forms to the latest version, but no use.

Comment: again, upgrade the shared code from PCL to .net standard 2.0, use MinVersion 16299 and use latest XF4.1